# Using PowerShell to download all files in a directory

Tags: powershell, ftp

I have a working PowerShell script that iterates through a directory accessed via FTP and prints it's contents. The script looks like this:

```
$sourceuri = "<string>"
$targetpath = "<string>"
$username = "<string>"
$password = "<string>"

# Create a FTPWebRequest object to handle the connection to the ftp server
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($sourceuri)

# set the request's network credentials for an authenticated connection
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails
$ftprequest.UseBinary = $true
$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $false

# send the ftp request to the server
$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()
$stream = $ftpresponse.getresponsestream()

$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024 
$encoding = new-object System.Text.AsciiEncoding 

$outputBuffer = "" 
$foundMore = $false 

## Read all the data available from the stream, writing it to the 
## output buffer when done. 
do 
{ 
    ## Allow data to buffer for a bit 
    start-sleep -m 1000 

    ## Read what data is available 
    $foundmore = $false 
    $stream.ReadTimeout = 1000 

    do 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            $read = $stream.Read($buffer, 0, 1024) 
            if($read -gt 0) 
            {

                $foundmore = $true 
                $outputBuffer += ($encoding.GetString($buffer, 0, $read)) 
            } 
        }
        catch
        { 
            $foundMore = $false; $read = 0 
        } 
    } 
    while($read -gt 0) 
} 
while($foundmore) 

$outputBuffer
```

My actual goal is not to just list the files but download them to the machine running the script. I'm finding this a bit tricky since my loops only reference bytes and not files by name. How can I use this loop to download all the files in a directory instead of just listing them?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use real FTP libraries like the one of winscp but there are other examples out there. http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory#example

Answer (score -1):

once you have a the list of directories and files - use the `get-content` method to read from the list, and then use the bits transfer to download all files - I'm not sure if this will download the directories as well... but it will definitely download the files...